# How to read data from oracle database by user inputted table name with condition?

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to read data from oracle database where user will input the table name. There is no problem here. But when i am adding any condition then it is showing error. The code has given below with stack trace.

```
    package jdbc_test;

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JDBC_Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String tableName=null;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int id=8;

            System.out.println("Enter the table name: ");
            tableName = input.nextLine();

            try
            {

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle12c", "system", "oracle12c");


                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();


                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from "+tableName+"where id='"+id+"'");

                System.out.printf("%15s%15s","Name","ID");

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.printf("\n%15s",rs.getString("name"));
                }

                con.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
          }
      }
```

Console:

```
Enter the table name: 
t
```

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

How can i read data of user specified table name with condition?

Comment: Maybe you only missed a space before "where"?

Comment: This example is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), and is setting you up for a bad future in programming. Please read more about [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 9):

Your example, *and* the provided answer "that works" is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). *Please* read up on this dangerous practice. I am therefore suggesting you do not use it.

You want to use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for column fields. Please read up on the importance of prepared statements, as it will prepare you for a better future in programming more secure solutions.

---

### Allowing the user to input the Table Name is *not* a good idea

Not only is this not a good idea, it's not even supported by `PreparedStatement`.

You cannot use a table name as parameter (`?`) in the prepared statements. You'll have to find another way to put it there, such as string concatenation, which is dangerous.

Unless you're using a pre-determined white-list, you *cannot* allow the table name to be chosen by the user, though, as that would allow SQL injection.

Credentials in repositories is another security risk.

You should also avoid putting the username and password directly into `getConnection()`. Use a secret manager or, at the very least, read from a properties file (bonus points if encrypted with a secret manager) that doesn't get committed to the repository.

Here's your fixed try block:

```
try
{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle12c", username, password);

    // You want to prepare a statement so you can pass parameters.
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement();

    // The first question mark (?)
    // Assuming this is an INT type. If not, there is setString, setLong, etc.
    ps.setInt(1, id);

    // Note the first question mark is where the ID is supposed to be. This is a parameter.
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from tableName where id = ?");

    while (rs.next())
    {
        // Replace "column_name" with the name of your column
        System.out.println(rs.getString("column_name"));
    }

    con.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```

If you are learning to code, whomever is telling you to do it the way you're doing it, is setting you up for a lifetime of very bad coding practices, which will lead to the companies you work for being hacked.

Answer (score -4):

Change `"select * from "+tableName+"where id='"+id+"'"` to `"select * from " + tableName + " where id='" + id + "'"`

Notice the space before where clause.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not use.

Comment: No need to negative mark. Surely I can go over the whole best way of doing but I highlighted the exact issue. You could have mentioned all right ways of doing JDBC in your answer.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale The fact that you solve his issue is irrelevant if you're inserting a very dangerous yet easily avoidable vulnerability in his program at the same time.

Comment: While I agree with Bhushan trying to help out the OP by pinpointing the problem, a word of caution on what he;s trying to do will make it a better answer. This doesn't deserve that many negative votes anyway.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale I'm sorry, I didn't intend to be negative... but I just can't let someone continue with an insecure solution.